# Create a folder on Local Folder of UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to create a folder named "TestFolder" on local folder of my uwp app. And need to upload files to it. It works fine on my system when I first manually create a folder((TestFolder) on local folder. but when I create app package for the project and tried to run it in another windows pc. It throws an error "System cant find the file specified". How can I resolve it?

```
 StorageFolder appFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("TestFolder");
            if (appFolder == null)
            {
                //Create folder
                appFolder = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("TestFolder");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would replace this few lines by this single line

```
var appFolder = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("TestFolder", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code this way to get your desired result,

```
StorageFolder appFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("TestFolder");
        if (appFolder == null)
        {
            //Create folder
            appFolder = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("TestFolder",CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        }
```